# A Little PIVOT Table Help Please

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

I am having some serious troubles getting this PIVOT table in TSQL to work properly.

Here is some sample code to reproduce the source table...

```
Declare @MyAssigneeTable table (
                            VDayID int, 
                            VDate datetime, 
                            StartTime varchar(100), 
                            EndTime varchar(100),
                            PositionID int,
                            RoomID int,
                            RoomDesc varchar(100),
                            Position varchar(100),
                            SortOrder int,
                            Assignee varchar(100)
                        )



INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Matt')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',15,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'Kevin')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Amber')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',15,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'Lawrence')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'Chad')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Kevin')
INSERT INTO @MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',16,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'')

Select * from @MyAssigneeTable
```

I think that I want to do some sort of PIVOT but I cannot get the desired output. In this below desired table script, I was needing the column names to be driven from distinct dates, the position column rows to be distinct values, and the cell intersecting the row and column to be the assignee. But this is too complex for me to figure out. Can this even be done? Here is a DDL to recreate the desired output.

```
Declare @MyDesiredTable table (
                            Position varchar(200), 
                            [2013-10-23] varchar(100), 
                            [2013-10-24] varchar(100), 
                            [2013-10-25] varchar(100)
                         )

INSERT INTO @MyDesiredTable VALUES('Room 1 / Position 1','','','Chad')
INSERT INTO @MyDesiredTable VALUES('Room 1 / Position 2','Matt','Amber','Kevin')
INSERT INTO @MyDesiredTable VALUES('Room 1 / Position 3','Kevin','Lawrence','')

Select * from @MyDesiredTable
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much for your assistance!!

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted?

Comment: I have tried to do basic PIVOT table examples (e.g. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/) using scripts like "Select *  from @MyAssigneeTable
PIVOT(Assignee FOR VDate IN (Select Distinct(VDate) from @MyAssigneeTable)) AS PVTTable". But I am getting syntax errors. I have no idea if this is even the correct approach. Most of the examples seem to do "AVG", "SUM", etc inside of the PIVOT clause. I don't want an aggregate function I don't believe. So a lifeline would be fantastic!! Thanks

Comment: A pivot table is a tool for preventing summaries.  The summary depends on use of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to build a list of dates (for the headers) and use MAX to get the assignee for the particular row.

Just going to paste the raw markdown from [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e87e/1):

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols= ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CAST(VDate AS date))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT VDate FROM MyAssigneeTable) AS Dates


SET @sql = N'
  SELECT Position, ' + @cols + '
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      Position = RoomDesc + '' / '' + Position, 
      Vdate = CAST(vdate as date), 
      Assignee 
    FROM MyAssigneeTable
  ) MyAssigneeTable
  PIVOT( MAX( Assignee )
  FOR MyAssigneeTable.vdate IN (' + @cols + ')) AS PivotTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e87e/1/0)**:

```
|            POSITION | 2013-10-23 | 2013-10-24 | 2013-10-25 |
|---------------------|------------|------------|------------|
| Room 1 / Position 1 |            |            |       Chad |
| Room 1 / Position 2 |       Matt |      Amber |      Kevin |
| Room 1 / Position 3 |      Kevin |   Lawrence |            |
```

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyAssigneeTable 
(
  VDayID int, 
  VDate datetime, 
  StartTime varchar(100), 
  EndTime varchar(100),
  PositionID int,
  RoomID int,
  RoomDesc varchar(100),
  Position varchar(100),
  SortOrder int,
  Assignee varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Matt')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2264, '2013-10-23', '7 AM','12 PM',15,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'Kevin')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Amber')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2265, '2013-10-24', '7 AM','12 PM',15,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'Lawrence')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',13,150,'Room 1','Position 1',99,'Chad')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',14,150,'Room 1','Position 2',99,'Kevin')
INSERT INTO MyAssigneeTable VALUES (2266, '2013-10-25', '7 AM','12 PM',16,150,'Room 1','Position 3',99,'')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to alter it a little for table variables but couldn't have done this without your help! Thank you so much JPW.